# Navigation controller with searchBar jump

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

I have a navigation controller in my main View where it includes a searchBar. Then when it goes to second View (without searchBar) there is a little jump on the screen, and same thing happens when I go back to first View.

Here is my Navigation controller code for first `viewController`:

```
func configureNavBar() {
    navigationController?.navigationBar.isTranslucent = false
    navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = .mainPink()
    navigationController?.navigationBar.barStyle = .black

    searchBar = UISearchBar()
    searchBar.delegate = self
    searchBar.tintColor = .white
    navigationItem.titleView = searchBar
    searchBar.showsCancelButton = true
}
```

Second:

```
navigationController?.navigationBar.isTranslucent = false
navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = .mainPink()
navigationController?.navigationBar.barStyle = .black
```

Is there any way to eliminate this 'jump' ?

Comment: Check my answer below, and please let me know if it works.

Comment: @AmrEl-Sayed unforetunately didn't work.

Comment: Can you show us a screenshot of the tableview constraints ? I’m speaking about the SecondViewController.

Comment: the second VC just shows the item that was selected in the first tableView VC, there is no tableView there.

Comment: I have tried your code to get what you intend. Kindly find my updated answer below. I hope It gets working fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This question actually contains two different issues:

1- In case of "Large Navigation Bar" suddenly collapsed when navigating to another View Controller:

The TableView scrolling is the main reason, Try the following:

> ```
> self.tableView.contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior = .never
> ```

You can set it from "Size Inspector" in storyboard also.

It adjusts its scroll position corresponding to the SafeArea.

---

2- The case of "Default Navigation Bar" that contains SearchBar in its Navigation Item's title view:

The main reason is that the search bar is added with height "56" by default

- Regarding a black line that appears under the navigation bar of the pushed view controller, So you can fix it with the following:

  ```
  // Inside ViewDidLoad of the Pushed View Controller

  self.extendedLayoutIncludesOpaqueBars = true
  ```

OR

```
override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
    navigationController?.view.setNeedsLayout() 
    navigationController?.view.layoutIfNeeded()
 }
```

- For preventing the NavigationBar to be extended at all when putting the SearchBar like this:

You need to create a custom view with a fixed height frame and add this search bar inside it, check the following:

class SearchBarViewHolder: UIView {

```
let searchBar: UISearchBar  

init(customSearchBar: UISearchBar) {  
    searchBar = customSearchBar  
    super.init(frame: CGRect.zero)  

    addSubview(searchBar)  
}

override convenience init(frame: CGRect) {  
    self.init(customSearchBar: UISearchBar())  
    self.frame = frame  
}  

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {  
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")  
}  

override func layoutSubviews() {  
    super.layoutSubviews()  
    searchBar.frame = bounds  
}  
}
```

// Adding Search bar

```
let searchBarViewHolder = SearchBarViewHolder(customSearchBar: searchBar)  
searchBarViewHolder.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: view.frame.width, height: 44)  
navigationItem.titleView = searchBarViewHolder
```